# How to solve siebel variables in Oracle Openscript

Tags: performance, openscript

How to solve siebel variables in Oracle Openscript?
How to solve siebel.solve to http.solve?
Getting the following error on creating a regular expression for the siebel variable:
'Siebel_CORRLIB_ROWID_1628008925187__RowID_N0_1_#_2115B330442" not found for string: {{*Siebel_CORRLIB_ROWID_1628008925187__RowID_N0_1*##_2115B330442}} '